# Changing field type of the layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes

I am using QGIS 3.28.2 I inserted a layer contains contour lines and added points as elevation points. However to enter elevation value into feature attribute, only one digit is allowed.

I tried to change the data type from `double` to `real` but I could not find `refactor` menu from processing.

Answer (score 5):

From the processing menu, search for ["Refactor fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) to change the data type:

[image]

However, if only one digit is allowed, I suspect you need to also change the Length of the field.